# DisplayString in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

What if we want to use DisplayString Method in Crystal Report but we want to apply this only on the basis of some parameter value ! ?
Like we will pass in parameter whether the use can see the purchase rate or not !
If not then we will print Asterisk instead of actual rate else do nothing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes a `boolean` parameter named {?hide}:

```
If {?hide} Then
    Replace(Space(Len(ToText(CurrentFieldValue,"#"))), " ", "*")
Else
    ToText(CurrentFieldValue)
```

Comment: I hope by converting the actual field value into string will not effect my arithmetic operation in the row . Thanks :)

Comment: The DisplayString formula will not affect its other (e.g. arithmetic, sorting) operations.